# How to delete on duplicate after trimming in mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace, trim

For example in the following data:

```
(1157)
(1157
1157
1145)
mydog5456
```

If I want to trim `(` and `)` in my table and if they record after replace is already exists then delete the record. What sql should I run?

I.E. result will be

```
1157
1145
mydog5456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '(', '');

UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ')', '');

UPDATE your_table 
SET your_field = TRIM(your_field );

ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(your_field);
```